# Hong Kong Visa and re-entry / Indian Citizen

Tags: indian-citizens, hong-kong

As an Indian citizen, I can get a visa on arrival in HK for a stay up to 14 days.

If I had to stay for longer, say 20 days, is it possible to leave Hong Kong for Macau/China and enter again? To be more precise, I leave HK on the 13th day of my contiguous stay and arrive back 2 days later to stay for another week or so.

Is there a potential problem with this plan?

Comment: I don't know whether entering China and coming back would reset the clock, but you'd need a visa to go to China anyway, and according to [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11507/is-it-pretty-easy-for-an-american-to-get-a-chinese-visa-in-hong-kong?rq=1), you'd need to apply for your Chinese visa back in India (or wherever you normally live). Why not just apply for a visa to visit Hong Kong for the duration of your stay?

Comment: As per new rules by Hong Kong immigration, Indian nationals need [Pre-Arrival registration](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/pre-arrival_registration_for_indian_nationals.html) before making use of 14-day visa free stay

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is standard practice that Indian visitors with Visa-on-arrival follow. Just make a trip to Macau, and enter again.